# I am getting a string error on a maths function in Ruby

Tags: ruby

This is a little program related to work:

```
#get refractive index
print "What is the surrounding refractive index?"
n = gets.chomp
puts n.to_f 
#get refractive index of the lens
print "What is the refractive index of the lens?"
n1 = gets.chomp
puts n1.to_f 
print "What is the radius of curvature of the lens?(mm)"
r= gets
puts r.to_f
F= (n1-n)/r
print "F={F}D"
```

This is an error:

```
undefined method `-' for "1.523":String
Did you mean?  -@
(repl):12:in `<main>'
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

> `undefined method '-' for "1.523":String`
>
> what does it mean?

It means, you can't do math with strings.

```
puts n.to_f
```

This line is meaningless. You first convert string `n` to a float number, then immediately `puts` converts it back to string for printing. (in the meanwhile, `n` itself is never touched/modified. It remains a string).

Convert your input to floats right away, as soon as you get it.

```
n = gets.chomp.to_f
```

Or, because, `to_f` will ignore trailing newlines, you can omit `chomp`

```
n = gets.to_f
```